# Unity - Programmatically cut holes of differing scale into plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and am trying to programmatically generate maps. I'd like to generate dynamic planes filled with holes, like Swiss cheese. I can't seem to find a straightforward way to cut through planes or meshes.

Any libraries, docs, or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "straight foreward" way to do this. 
My approach to this would be to calculate a grid of edges like a matrix and use the x and y of the edges as input to a perlin noise for example.
If the result is below a certain value you mark this edge as "non drawable".
After that you just have to create the faces. Always take 3 edges and create a face between them. 
But if one of those edges is markes as "non drawable", then dont create the face.

Should do the trick :) 
Although im sure you have to fiddle around with the values a bit to get the result you want. Also the polycount of this is not optimal. But with some work im sure you can find a solution with dynamic resolution.

Here is a short tutorial on how to create a mesh from code: 
https://youtu.be/gmuHI_wsOgI

And here is a short tutorial on using perlin noise in Unity: 
https://youtu.be/gmuHI_wsOgI

ofc. there are also other noise functions that might have a pattern that looks more like what you are going for.